# What is the significance of t-stats value while applying ttest_ind on two pandas series?

Tags: pandas, scipy, t-test

what conclusion can be drawn from the resulting t-stats value When ttest_ind is applied on two independent series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html), the `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` has two outputs

- The calculated t-statistic.
- The two-tailed p-value.

Very intuitively, you can read the t-statistic as a normalized difference of averages in both populations, considering their variances and sizes:

- The larger are the samples, the more serious the difference of averages is because we have more evidence for that.
- The larger are the variances, the less serious the difference of averages is because the absolute difference can be given by randomness only.

The higher is the value of the t-statistic, the more serious is the difference.

The p-value makes this intuition more explicit: it is the probability that the difference of averages can be considered as zero. If the p-value is bellow a threshold, e.g. 0.05, we say that the difference in not zero.